# how can I check if a function is processing multiple curlied arguments in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Just a curious question. I'm trying to detect if a function is multiple currlies during the runtime; eg I want to make following statements both work

```
add(1, 2, 3); // 6
add(1)(2)(3); // 6
add(1, 2)(3); // 6
add(1)(2, 3); // 6
```

First I need solve is to detect if the function is processing a multi curlied arguments or not. Here is my testing cases.

```
isMultipleCurly()(); // true   
isMultipleCurly()()(); // true  
isMultipleCurly(); // false
```

so how can I check if function is processing multiple curlied arguments?

Comment: You could check if the returned value is a function

Comment: Do you mean "curried"?

Comment: @Barmar, passing argument by curlies. (also my typo ...)

Comment: @Dale, the question is how can I check if there are curlies?

Comment: @WeijingLin What are curlies? The only thing I can think of like that is curly braces, which are `{}`, but you're not using that in your code.